# How to "drag and drop" folders or multiple HTML files into a browser and have them open in multiple tabs

Tags: browser, plugins, drag-and-drop

I save pages that I browse on the net and find interesting into a folder called C:\PageSaves

Later, during the commute, I open these pages to see what they are and move them into a neatly categorized folder tree.

For example, Perl related pages goto C:\Pages\Perl, MySQL related pages goto C:\Pages\MySQL and so on.

I was wondering if there is any way I could

1. open any number of HTML files on
   disc / inside a folder (C:\PageSaves
   in my case) into Mozilla/FF/K-Meleon
   etc

   For example, I would like to just
   "drag and drop" the folder
   C:\PageSaves into FireFox and  have
   it open all the .html pages in the
   folder in a separate tab

   Right now, if I "drag and drop"
   multiple HTML files, it just opens
   the last file in the selection.
2. Have a set of toolbar buttons,
   basically, a (the) plugin that
   should allow me to nuke the page (if
   I don't want to keep the page
   anymore) from disc or move the file
   (and its corresponding folder) into
   a predefined / new folder

I am familiar with coding full blown FireFox plugins, so even if something very basic/almost similar exists, I can take it forward.

Hints/clues/other methods of achieving the same result are all welcome!

Comment: Is your question about all browsers, or only Firefox, like the content seems to indicate ? About other browsers, IE calls the windows explorer when d&d a folder, Chrome and Opera open the folder on a "fileserver" way, showing the folder's content in a generated webpage (with links to the elements).

Comment: As I said, I would like to open each page in a separate tab. Also, I would rather not focus on IE but would like to focus on something portable like FF extensions as I find it easy to code (Javascript + XUL)

Answer (score 1):

You save entire pages in hierarchical folders? Or do you mean you save bookmark shortcuts?

Your file system is absolutely the worst bookmark manager you could possibly have chosen, and backing the Internet up onto your personal computer is unnecessary at best. Rather than reinvent the wheel, why not use something designed to manage large collections of bookmarks?

You can perform a search for 'bookmark manager' and find a thousand solutions; you can use [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/), you can use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/), you can use [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/), you can use any one of [these](http://mashable.com/2007/08/16/firefox-bookmarks/)...

Personally, I use delicious.com and its Firefox plugin. When I come across a page I want to read later, I tag it as "read-later." When the time comes, I read the page and edit the tag.

- Benefits: (1.) I can check my read-later tag from every device I have, including my phone and my Kindle. (2.) Individual bookmarks can have multiple tags. (3.) If my laptop gets dropped off a cliff, my bookmarks still exist online. (4.) I can share my bookmarks with others.
- Drawbacks: (1.) This solution won't open multiple bookmarks into tabs. (2.) You need to be connected to utilize this solution.

If you *must* organize your bookmarks while offline, I'd suggest setting your browser to cache pages and using its built-in bookmark manager, rather than saving pages onto your hard drive and using your file system to organize them.

**Also:** while Firefox doesn't know how to open multiple locally-saved pages into tabs, it does know how to open *shortcuts* into separate tabs. So maybe you could figure out some way to save pages locally and then make a shortcuts to them in, say, a bookmarks folder called PageSaves. Then you could open all your pages into tabs at once, even if they are local.

Comment: Do any of these services make a complete local backup of the pages (pictures, and other resources attached, etc)?

I have been using this technique since 96 when such services never existed, and most of the bookmarked sites are dead, but I still have what I need.

If there is a service that promises me this with very little chance of disappearing, do let me know.

Comment: No, none of these services make complete local backups of online resources; they merely allow you to organize bookmarks. (If your intent is truly to archive the internet, I'm afraid my answer is useless to you. It seemed so weird that you'd actually be saving copies of web pages locally that I thought you must have meant 'bookmark.' Apologies for misunderstanding.)

Comment: It's OK. I just have been burned many times with websites shutting down, breaking URLs, going behind paywalls etc that saving interesting pages seems the best way out.

Comment: Ah, you're an information hoarder? ;-)

Comment: Objectively, yes :-D

Answer (score 0):

With *nix / bash, you can do `firefox /path/to/pages/*.html`. Windows powershell might have something similar, or you could install cygwin to get *nix/bash under Windows.